# Spring MVC with hibernate in an ear application using only annotation is not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have created ear project with one web module and one EJB module.

I'm using web module for Spring MVC view and controller. Model, service and repository are maintained in ejb module. (tried in JAR module as well).

I'm getting exception like, `[springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 168) Context initialization failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.sakthi.core.config.HibernateConfiguration Exception.`

My HibernateConfiguration class is,

```
package com.sakthi.core.config;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.sakthi.core.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }

}
```

My Complete project is copied in github URL: https://github.com/newway86/Spring4MVCHibernateEAR/tree/master/myapp

Please help me... I'm trying for 2 months. Not yet getting the sollution.

This actual program has been taken from this URL: http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-and-hibernate4-integration-example-using-annotations/

If I try the above example in web project, its working fine. But not working while I create it as a ear project and moved the core logics to the ejb module.

Comment: I have found the solution. The fix is, while we autowire web to ejb module beans, i have tried with constructor injection. Its working fine now.